# Understanding Cancan abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Trying to get Cancan securing a few models in an application and curious why it's not working the way I thought it would. I had thought you could `can?` on the specific instance as opposed to the entire class so, not in this example but, you could enable abilities on a per instance basis as a list of posts are displayed?!?

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user) 
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :moderator
      can :manage, Post
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end

# posts/index.html.haml
...
- if can? :update, @post   <- doesn't work
- if can? :update, Post    <- works
```

**Edit**: add PostsController.rb

```
#posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [:index, :show]
  load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create]

  def index
    # @posts = Post.all ## <- handled by Cancan's load_and_authorize_resource
    @events = Event.where("end_date <= :today", :today => Date.today)
    @next_event = Event.next

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: You can use that first method, what does your controller for the index action look like?

Comment: ok. added above...wonder if `load_and_authorize_resource` is causing trouble...but it's Cancan's method so I wouldn't expect it to...

Comment: And your view code as well, forgot to ask for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
- if can? :update, @post   <- doesn't work
```

Is asking CanCan "can I update this specific post." You defined the ability in terms of all posts. If you had done:

```
can :update, Post, :user_id => user.id
```

Then your "if can?" would work, and the user would only be able to update their own posts. So you want to use the specific resource version ("@post") if something about this instance of the resource determines the permission, and you want to use the class version ("Post") if the user has the ability for all instances of the class.